# How to redirect a deleted directory to the root?

Tags: .htaccess

How to rewrite when someone tries to access any files/pages in a deleted directory?  Want to send them to the root if they do.

```
mysite.com/deleted_dir/page1.php
mysite.com/deleted_dir/page2.php
```

TO

```
mysite.com
```

Comment: Do you want to serve content from the root path without also changing the browser address bar from the non-existing page, or do you actually want to _redirect_ the user to the root?  Is this to happen only for .php scripts, or any non-existent path?  Apache doesn't have any way to tell the difference between a _deleted_ path and one that never existed at all.

Comment: Just wanted to keep users from getting 404 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the document root's htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/deleted_dir/ /
```